# WPF calculated ViewModel and property changed notification

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I stumbled on this problem a few days ago and nothing seems to give me a solution - or, at least, an idea. In my ViewModel A I have a calculated property that produces an ObservableCollection of ViewModels B. I can bind to this collection no problem, but changes in the properties of ViewModel B items don't show up in the UI. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated and don't hesitate to ask for any clarification or detail. Thanks in advance!

Update: Here's the property that doesn't notify

```
public Boolean IsHighlighted
{
     get { return _IsHighlighted; }
     set
     {
          if (_IsHighlighted != value)
          {
               _IsHighlighted = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("IsHighlighted");
          }
      }
}
```

and the calculated property that produces the collection in ViewModel A

```
public ObservableCollection<PointViewModel> MidPoints
        {
            get
            {
                ObservableCollection<PointViewModel> midPoints = new ObservableCollection<PointViewModel>();
                // 
                //....calculations
                //
                return midPoints;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It would help if you showed us ViewModelB

Comment: It's too long to paste here but it provides property change notification through a BaseViewModel abstract class

Comment: We can't help without you showing us some code. Sorry.

Comment: Then just paste one property that doesnt update

Comment: See the update (sorry about the mess!!!)

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please edit your question instead of posting code in comments.

Comment: Don't create a new ObservableCollection in the MidPoints getter. Instead, create the collection once and later only modify it (i.e. add and remove elements). Otherwise you would have to raise the PropertyChanged event for MidPoints.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, Clemens! Therefore I have to ditch the calculated property and define it as a normal property, right?

Comment: Can you show us your XAML ?

Comment: @Clemens there is a problem with binding of the PointViewModel properties. And IsHighlighted notifies its changes. there is a problem with XAML Binding

Comment: @Clemens You dont need notification when your binding is oneway or onefirst, or when you don't need to set your property. secondly, the problem isn't with the collection, but with a property of an element of the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create a new `ObservableCollection<PointViewModel>` instance in the `MidPoints` property getter.

Instead, perform add and delete operations on the existing instance:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<PointViewModel> midPoints
    = new ObservableCollection<PointViewModel>();

public ObservableCollection<PointViewModel> MidPoints
{
    get { return midPoints; }
}

public void UpdateMidPoints()
{
    // performs calculations that add and remove elements to/from midPoints
    // ...
}
```

---

In case it is for whatever reason required to create a new collection instance, you would have to raise the PropertyChanged event:

```
private ObservableCollection<PointViewModel> midPoints;

public ObservableCollection<PointViewModel> MidPoints
{
    get { return midPoints; }
    set
    {
         midPoints = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("MidPoints");
    }
}

public void UpdateMidPoints()
{
    ObservableCollection<PointViewModel> newMidPoints
        = new ObservableCollection<PointViewModel>();
    // 
    // calculations...
    //
    MidPoints = newMidPoints;
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up with, except for the update process which happens outside my ViewModel.